# environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not working until I reassign it

Tags: linux, bash, embedded-linux

I have a strange behavior on an embedded linux system. It is created from an image file and has been used on many system for about a year without any issues. But a new system that I installed just now fail to work.

I have an app that is started by one of the boot scripts, and is dependent on a library foo.so in a special path.

So the script sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH to foopath.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foopath \
foo.app
```

But after boot I can see that the app was never started and if I try to start it manually it complains that it can't find the library.

The strange thing is that I can get it to work by setting the same path again by just copying the path using the clipboard, like this:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
foopath
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foopath
```

After this my app will find the library and executes correct.
But if I reboot the system the problem is of course back again.

What could be wrong, and what can I do to solve the issue?

As seen in the comments I got it to work by changing my script like this, but I still can't understand why it works on some systems, but not all.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foopath
foo.app
```

Comment: Probably it's set as a regular shell variable before but not exported as an environment variable

Comment: Don't use `echo` to test. Instead run `declare -p LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. If the output starts with `declare -x` it's exported; `declare --` means it's stored only in heap memory and not in the environment.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, declare -p confirms that LD_LIBRARY _PATH is not exported. But how can I make sure that it is exported?
The script is located in /etc/rc5.d/S95_foo.sh
I tried to use declate -x, declare -gx and export in this script file, but all of them end up with declare -p returning --

Comment: I'd need to see a [mre] that shows both where the export is happening and how that relates to the context where the variable _isn't_ exported. (Environment variables are only inherited by children of the process where the export takes place; if you do the export in a subshell, it doesn't apply to the parent, f/e).

Comment: BTW, typically your `rc5.d` directory and similar should have _symlinks_ into `/etc/init.d`; that way you aren't deleting/renaming the script itself when you change its startup priority or which runlevels it runs in. (But I don't recommend using SysV-style init at all; [`runit`](http://smarden.org/runit/), [`s6`](https://skarnet.org/software/s6/) and other software inspired by [DJB daemontools](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) are a better middle ground for situations where systemd-esque tooling is inappropriate).

Comment: ...anyhow, I'd suggest starting small. Add a `declare -p` _right after_ the `export`. If the `-x` shows up there but not somewhere else, you have two locations and you can look at what happens between them.

Comment: Problem solved by using export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foopath in the script instead of running LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foopath foo.app. i.e. I was using it locally when the app was executed. This works but I do not really understand why it worked on some systems, but not all. using declare -p in the login shell might be too late...

Comment: _All in one line_, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foopath foo.app` _does_ do an export for the duration of `foo.app`'s execution, though it doesn't set the variable at all in a way that lasts after `foo.app` has finished or otherwise impacts later lines in the same script.

Comment: Of course, your question didn't ever show that you were originally running `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foopath foo.app` at all, so nobody here could have spoken to it regardless. Make sure, when asking questions here, that you're including _everything needed_ for someone else to see the problem themselves.

Comment: Hmm. "Some systems but not all"... is `foo.app` setuid, or otherwise something in a different security context than the parent process? Well-secured operating systems drop `LD_` configuration options from the environment when crossing that boundary.

Comment: See https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/NotableWryLink#main.sh demonstrating that for a _regular_ variable (excluding the special case `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`), `variable=value` works as you expect.

Comment: In the situation where it does not work, what is the result of "strace -f foo.app" ?